# nouveau/nvc0_fuc084 failed with error -2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

These messages appear in logwatch.

WARNING:  Kernel Errors Present
nouveau 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvc0_fuc084 failed with error -2 ...:  3 Time(s)
nouveau 0000:05:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvc0_fuc084d failed with error -2 ...:  3 Time(s)

I don't see any problems with the video output but still I wonder.
Googling these gets some answers but none seem to apply to this situation with a fix.
One mentions info from https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/VideoAcceleration.html showing the gforce 400 is missing some firmware that can be extracted from the nvidia and gives instuctions on how to do it if you distrubution is not on their short list.  Which ubuntu isn't.
Does anyone have any further information about this?

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Dell precision t7600
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100GL [Quadro 4000] (rev a3)
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: GF100GL [Quadro 4000]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: a3
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
resources: irq:75 memory:d0000000-d1ffffff memory:c0000000-c7ffffff memory:c8000000-cbffffff ioport:7000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

Thanks
Jim